# Youtube-dl facebook video asks login details in remote server?

Tags: video, python3, remote, youtube-dl, facebook

I was working on a project which uses youtube-dl, when I was working on the project from my local machine it worked fine without any problems but when I tried to run the same project in a remote VM (Google cloud compute engine) which is situated in India only, I am getting an error like this

`ERROR: This video is only available for registered users. Use --username and --password or --netrc to provide account credentials`.

So I gave my Facebook credentials but still, it's giving me the same error.

I also tried to download it directly from the terminal

```
youtube-dl <video-url> --username "<username>" --password "<password"
```

But still, I face the same error

any solution is appreciated

Thank you